# Function for alpha and single space only

Tags: javascript

I have a function to make people enter alphabet only onkeypress

```
function isAlfa(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have another function to prevent them from typing double spaces

```
function checkstuff(event){
if(event.target.value.substr(-1)=== ' ' && event.code === 'Space')

{
//alert('space clicked twice');
//remove space from the last.
event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(0,event.target.value.length-1);
}

debugger;

var evt = (event) ? event : window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
console.log(charCode)
    return false;
}
console.log('valid '+charCode)
return true;
}
```

I've been trying to put the two together into one function with no success. I tried running them both `onkeypress`, but it only runs the first. How can I merge the 2 functions?

Comment: where have you tried merging them? I dont see it here

Comment: can you store global variables ?

Comment: I tried a few things to put the isalpha code into the other, but didn't work

Comment: @Greggz what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the part of alphabetical checking, you can add the function to check the double spaces as follows.

```js
function isAlfa(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if(evt.target.value.substr(-1) === ' ' && evt.keyCode === 32) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return isAlfa(event)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use state for the previous input

```
const spaceCode = 32;
var lastCharCode = undefined;

function isAlfa(evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  
  if (lastCharCode == spaceCode && charCode == spaceCode) {
    throw new Error('No double space allowed');
  }

  lastCharCode = charCode;
  
  if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```